# Why don't my marksdwarves do any damage?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to augment my melee troops with some ranged troops.  However the ranged troops don't seem to be effective at all, even though they're all `Skilled` or better.

For example:

- 30 wood and bone bolts against a naked goblin resulted in bruises only.
- 30 wood and bone bolts against an armored goblin resulted in nothing.

  - Bolts were even stopped by silk clothes.
- 30 *iron* bolts against an armored goblin resulted in absolutely nothing.

  - Noted bolts being stopped by copper and leather.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the state of ranged combat in 0.31.12?

Comment: Did they forget to take the rubber tips off first?

Comment: @antony That's what I was wondering.

Comment: what's the quality of bolts and crossbow that you are using?

Comment: @Doltknuckle.  I know it included high quality bone and wood bolts.  Less so for the iron bolts, and the crossbows are of various quality.

Comment: Note: Steel helps a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked around the forums and the general consensus is that military is still unbalanced. For the "armored" creatures, the protection given by clothing and armor is way overpowered. Here's a useful video: http://mkv25.net/dfma/movie-2048-crossbowsgotnerfedtoomuch

Another problem with archery is that it has a low percentage hit chance when your enemies are moving. It could be that most of your shots are missing, and those that hit do low damage. I usually use cage traps to get some invaders and then set up the cages in an "execution pit". When the enemies are not moving, it can take anywhere from 20-50 direct hits to actually kill an invader.

Try out arena mode and see what happens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: RE the video: OH THE HUMANITY!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely not the hit count though.  I can see "hits" in the combat reports.

Comment: That is incredible, man.